# got error for injecting my custom service in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I can't inject my custom service in Jasmine. The error is [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider. I have created Plunker `<a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/hoOHky54TIqnjAizR986?p=preview">example </a>`, click run and you will see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to include

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

in jasmine-test-runner.html.

see http://plnkr.co/edit/W19IYMR4uDFCq46j6AdR?p=preview